# Spring boot JDBCConnectionException in multiple data source connection

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc

We are getting JDBCConnection Exception when we try to use spring boot multiple data source connection, The connection is good for one day, but the next day getting connection exception, We need to restart the tomcat then its working fine, Can any body help us in the exact property which causes connection closing after some time

```
spring.xy.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://azurnae-db013.xxx.yy.net:3306/devdb
spring.xy.datasource.username=user
spring.xy.datasource.password=pass
spring.xy.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.xy.datasource.pool-size=100

Below is the excpetion

could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement",
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration for a tomcat webapp:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/itsme" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          maxTotal="100" 
          initialSize="1"
          maxActive="85"
          maxIdle="15"
          minIdle="1"
          maxWait="10000" 
          maxAge="3600000"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="60000"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="30000"
          testOnBorrow="true"
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
```

the property that you need are **minIdle, validationQuery, validationInterval, testOnBorrow** with these configured you should not have your problem anymore